# Issue with nodejs Promise sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi in the below function when i print the log file i could see the messages displayed in the below order though promise is used for synchronous communication.

Displayed sequence -

a)"before call"
b "after call"
c)"inside save"
d)"no issues"

What do i change in the code to get the order of logs as below-

a)"before call"
b) "after call"
c)**"no issues"**
d)"inside save"

Controller code -

```
module.exports.updateLocalTransportVendorDtls = function (req, res) {

    var transportSchema = new transportModel();

    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        checkForNewVehicleType(req, function (doc) {
            resolve(doc)
        })
    })
    .then(function (doc) {

        var updateJustServiceDtls = doc.split(/\|/)[2];
        var updateVehicle = doc.split(/\|/)[0];
        var addVehicle = doc.split(/\|/)[1];

        if (updateJustServiceDtls == 'true') { /* To update service details for the same vendor */
            console.log("before call")
            updateJustServiceDetailsOnly(req, res)
            console.log("after call")        
        }

    }).then(function () {
        console.log("inside save")
        transportSchema.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {               
                return res.status(500).json({ "Message": error.message.trim() });
            }
            else {
                return res.json({ "Message": "Data got inserted successfully in local_transport_details collection" });
            }
        })

    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.json({ "Message": err.message });
    });
}
```

function call-

```
var updateJustServiceDetailsOnly = function (req, res) {

    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                //code to update db
                console.log("no issues")
                resolve();
            });
    })
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `after call`, you can omit it if it is only log and return the result of the `updateJustServiceDetailsOnly`.

The **return** will force to pass execution to the next then when the `updateJustServiceDetailsOnly`'s promise will be settled. But after that line no code will work. If you want the desired result you need to remove the part after return.

```
if (updateJustServiceDtls == 'true') {
    console.log("before call")
    return updateJustServiceDetailsOnly(req, res)
    // console.log("after call")  this will not be called
}
```

With this code the result will be

```
a)"before call" b)"no issues" c)"inside save"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return your Promise.

```
 if (updateJustServiceDtls == 'true') { /* To update service details for the same vendor */
        console.log("before call")
        return updateJustServiceDetailsOnly(req, res)
        console.log("after call")        
 }
```

In that case obviously after call won't be logged. But just move the log in the next `.then`.

When you are in the Promise chain, if you have another Promise to do and you want to wait for it,  just return it.

Example:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
    // I have an async to do, I return it to wait for it
    return Promise.resolve('after call');
})
.then((result) => {
    // it will be called only when the Promise returned in the previous chain will resolve
    // the result is the data passed in the resolution of your promise
    console.log(result); // after call
});
```